# jest how can test axios?

Tags: testing, jestjs

No matter how I write, asynchronous problems occur.

test.js：

```
const auth = require('../methods/auth.js');

describe('test', () => {
    test('test', async () => {
      expect.assertions(1);
      const data = await auth.signin();
      return expect(data.success).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

auth.js：

```
module.exports = {
  async signin(data) {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post('/signin', data);
      return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return error.response;
    }
  },
}
```

Each execution result is different.

Comment: can you please share your message error?

Comment: @KickButtowski It will be the result of non-synchronization, sometimes the login is successful and sometimes the login fails

Comment: Where is your auth mock?

Comment: @KickButtowski Thank you very much for your concern, I got the answer through the second example below :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test Promises as follows:

```
test('test awaiting it to resolve', () => {
   // Don't await. Note the return; test callback doesn't need to be async
   // What I do in my tests as its more readable and the intention is clear
   return expect(auth.signin()).resolves.toEqual({success: true});
});

test('test the promises way', () => {
   // Not better than above; traditional way; note 'return'
   return auth.signin().then(data => { expect(data.success).toBeTruthy() });
});
```

**Detailed notes from jest:** https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#promises

Comment: Thank you, if I want to save the result returned by signin, should I write the following?

test('登入帳號', async () => {
      const data = auth.signin();
      signin = data;
      return expect(data).resolves.toEqual({ success: true });
    });

Comment: You can use option two in my answer, if you have further test from the data. If it helped, kindly upvote or mark the answer if its closes your question.

Comment: Thank you, I use the second method to solve the problem with return.

Because I need to use jest to simulate API operation behavior to ensure that the API is normal, I need some token storage behavior